# Unusual heat rise on rectifier

Tags: power-supply, rectifier, heat

Trying to refresh my knowledge I was design and construct a fixed unregulated power supply 12V/5A using parts that I have around. Parts are 150VA/12V toroid, an 25A rectifier bridge in 
[KBPC case](http://datasheet.seekic.com/datasheet/KBPC25005/W_Vishay.html) and 20 electrolytic capacitors 1000μF/35V each. 
Trying to calculate a plate  heatsink for the rectifier, I test my construction with an ohmic load (a tungsten lamp rated 55W/12V) and monitoring the rectifier case temperature
[image]
I find the temperature rise abnormal and  I cut the power around 100oC, then I remove the capacitor bank, and get temperature again 
[image]

This is the graph 
[image]

I can not explain the reason of this difference in temperature rise. I used another rectifier but no deference even using a 35A one.
The maximum current during charging period is calculated about 33A but it lasts just 1,8ms and with a duty cycle 0.22 the total dissipation is about 6.6W in total.
In no load condition, there is no consumption  by the capacitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its going to come downto powerflow and how "DC" your DClink is.

Without the cap the 55W bulb will be provided with ABS(Sin) voltage

[image]

This provides an RMS voltage of Vpk/1.414 and thus the power reduced.
the 55W/12V bulb is an equiv of: 2.618R
with an XFMR giving out 14.1pk voltage => 9.97Vrms => 37.98W

Now when you add the capacitors, you are "smoothing" the DClink
[image]
This increases the power supplied to the resistive load as it is now a DClevel.
20mF worth or capacitance should provide a DC output.
14.1V on the DClink =>  75.939W
Increased power, increased heating.

Comment: Yes indeed this is correct. However my question was about the power that this specific device can handle (i.e 25A) versus the requested current by the load (6~7A). A deep study in the manufacturers data and recalculations indicates that even for 7A rms (causing a total 6~7W dissipation on the bridge), the case temperature in free air rises to about 115oC which is "normal", since junction temperature maintains to about 135oC. So to use a KBPC rectifier in free-air, should be consider very carefully. Is it trough that this package case it is designed to use mainly in motorcycles?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if it is a coincidence, but when we draw a reverse derating curve (in red) this gives the case temperature rice in free air as a function of  current. 
If  derating curve slope considered as 1/Rθjc, the reverse is a plot of  Rθjc.
Is this correct?

[image]